# Does x64 mono require x64 class library?

Tags: .net, c++, mono, x86-64

I compiled an **x64** mono (version **2.11**) on Windows.

I noticed that every program that use a class library (System.Net, System.IO, ...) crash systematically.
I downloaded the latest version of [class library](http://mono.ximian.com/daily/), it works ok on x86 but not on x64.

Does x64 mono require x64 class library ?

The x64 compatibity issue on Windows prevented us from using mono on many projects. 
We decided to give it a try, I hope it works fine this time.

Comment: You can't mix 64bit and 32bit libraries which is what seems to be happening here. Any update?

Comment: Every program that I run still crashs :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, a 64-bit mono runtime does not require a different set of class libraries than a 32-bit mono runtime.

You do however need to ensure your version of the class libraries matches the version the runtime is expecting. If they didn't match you will normally get an error message to the console on startup.

A coworker and I did the port of the mono runtime to Windows x64. It is not as well tested as the 32-bit runtime, and so your errors may in fact be bugs. Please file any issues here:

http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Comment: Thanks, but in our case the program crash, with no errors messages.
We did a simple x64 compile, are there some special settings ?
(In the 32-bit version it display the errors message if the class libraries are outdated).

Comment: Might be a bit offtopic but how did you manage to compile mono for windows? I tried and failed so many times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .NET behaviors differently. In a x64 .NET process, you cannot use x86 assemblies either.

So for by design things, play politely with the rules. Don't try to cross the line.

Comment: Actually, most of .Net assemblies are CPU-agnostic. Only mixed-mode and P/Invokes require specifying the CPU type.

Comment: I am not sure if you know the meaning of "agnostic". The simple fact is that a 64 bit process never loads 32 bit dll. So if you are running mono.exe in 64 bit mode, and your assembly is x86 dependent (32 bit), mono.exe cannot load it, which is by design. From what @Simon.Jacobi stated, the problem can be this one.